# Open 3D binary image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binaryfiles

I'm trying to open a .bin file in Matlab. The file is a xcat phantom of human body.

dims: 320,128,666
vxsize: 2.5,2.5,2.5
data type: 32-bit float, littleendian

And what I want is to open/see image of a specific slice of this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCAT phantom comes in raw format. Just use `fopen`, `fread` (with the precision flag set to the correct type) and `fclose`. Then you will likely need to `reshape` what `fread` returns.

Once you have the 3D image in MATLAB, then just slice it with indexes `img(:,100,:)`